# Boostrap remote modal: Delay animation until after loading

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I am using Bootstrap v3.3.0 with remote loaded modals.  The remote modals are working fine, but I notice the fade effect is not as smooth as when a modal is pre-loaded with content instead of the remote loading that I am using.  The AJAX call is very small for all of my modals, so I don't want/need a loading indicator or progress bar, I would just like to delay the fade animation until after the content has been remotely loaded (which is never more than a fraction of a second).  Is there a way using javascript/jquery to specify the delaying of the fade-in animation until after the content has been loaded?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a delay with pure CSS:

```
.fade{
    -webkit-transition-delay: .5s;  // make this however long you need
    transition-delay: .5s;
  }
```

Also, if the vertical animation is a problem too, you can disable it with:

```
.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    -o-transform: none;
    transform: none;
```

}
      }

Comment: The transition-delay to the .fade class worked perfectly for me.  Adding just a .1s delay makes the fade and vertical transformation smooth as butter again.  Such a simple solution that I didn't think of.